# How to prove convergence of the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, means

Let $$a_0>b_0>0 $$and consider the infinite sequences $$\{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$$ where

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$$ and $${b_{n+1}}={(a_nb_n)}^{1/2} $$ for $n\geq0$.

Prove that the infinite sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ are convergent.

Can anyone guide me for this question? Thanks!

Comment: Not only do these sequences converge, but they converge to the same limit -- the so-called [Arithmetic-Geometric Mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean). I edited the title to mention this.

Answer (score 1):

First observe the followings:

$1)$: $\forall n \geq 0, a_n > 0, b_n > 0$

$2)$: $\forall n \geq 1, a_n \geq b_n$. This will lead to:

$3)$: $\forall n \geq 1, a_{n+1} < a_n$.

$4)$: $\forall n \geq 1, b_n < b_{n+1}$.

The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing, and bounded below by $0$, and the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is increasing, and bounded above by $a_0 > 0$.

Thus both sequences are convergent by Bolzano's criteria, and infact their limits are equal.

Comment: why 2)  is true? how to show $$a_n>=b_n $$ for n>=1

Answer (score 1):

BY AM-GM inequality, we can obtain that,$${b_{n+1}}=(a_nb_n)^{1/2}\le \dfrac{({a_n}+{b_n})}{2}=a_{n+1}.$$ Therefore 
$$b_{n+1}=(a_nb_n)^{1/2}\ge(b_nb_n)^{1/2}=b_n.$$ Hence $(b_n)$ is a increasing sequence and similarly $$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{({a_n}+{b_n})}{2}\le \dfrac{({a_n}+{a_n})}{2}=a_n$$ the sequence $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence. Try to show that both sequence are bdd. Then use the [Monotone Convergent Theorem](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMonotone_convergence_theorem&ei=aXI4VcriK8X4mAWnyID4CQ&usg=AFQjCNG0B8Vd7kpEWDEVGLMvNMyA_nQnvQ&bvm=bv.91427555,d.dGY).

Comment: why the first inequality is true? in other words:why $$a_n>=b_n $$ for n>=1

Comment: Geometric mean of two positive  numbers is always not greater than to  their Arithmetic mean. This is called the AM-GM inequality